# Why can't I see $WCREV$ in set dos command after executing SubWCRev.exe subversion tool?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I can successfully execute SubWCRev.exe on Windows. It does show revision number. But typing set under dos command doesn't list any $WCREV$ var. So where is it stored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SubWCRev.exe help output, this is the expected command line:

> Usage: `SubWCRev WorkingCopyPath [SrcVersionFile DstVersionFile] [-nmdf]`

and this is what it does with the `SrcVersionFile` and `DstVersionFile` arguments if you give them:

> SubWCRev reads the Subversion status
>   of all files in a working copy
>   excluding externals. If SrcVersionFile
>   is specified, it is scanned for
>   special placeholders of the form
>   "$WCxxx$". SrcVersionFile is then
>   copied to DstVersionFile but the
>   placeholders are replaced with
>   information about the working copy as
>   follows:

```
$WCREV$         Highest committed revision number
...
```